# How to get send sms in other Android sms manager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to check for sending sms in my application like below question?

can i check each sms that send by any other applications and i can use information of that message like phone number and body,for example: when the sms recived ,broadcastreciver for getting sms ,how can get information
 from sending sms?

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2):

You can always query the Provider for messages that have been sent, but I think you're interested in them *as* they are sent. For this, you can use a [`ContentObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) set for the `content://sms` URI, which will notify you when a message is written to the Provider. You can then query the Provider for whichever details you need.

However, this might not work everywhere, as SMS apps may vary, and are not required to use the standard system Provider. Additionally, you have no control over the state or content of messages sent by other apps.